# Using SAM4 series microcontroller with Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino-ide, bootloader

I am looking to use SAM4S series microcontroller by Atmel/Microchip and trying to program it using Arduino IDE.

1. Can I use the bootloader provided by Adafruit for [Feather M4 Express](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3857) [uses SAMD51]  or  [Feather M4 Can Express](https://www.adafruit.com/product/4759) [uses SAME51] both of which are ARM Cortex M4 based just like the SAM4S series?

If yes, how do I work around few different features such as different FLASH memory and RAM of my SAM4S16B IC compared to that of SAMD51 or SAME51?

2. Could you suggest any other ways for using SAM4S with Arduino IDE? I, personally, did not find any direct resources for the same.
3. Is it even possible to use SAM4S with Arduino IDE provided that I don't have to write my own bootloader or API's etc?

Appreciate your help in the matter.
Thank you.

Comment: If no one has written a SAM4 core for Arduino then no, you can't. If someone has, then the resources you need will be in that core and their respective website / repository.

Comment: As for "Can I use any old Arm M4 based code?" the answer is a vehement "no". Just cus the CPU is M4 doesn't make it the same chip. It's like old home computers. The C64 and BBC both used the 6502, but you won't run code for one on the other.

Comment: Thanks Majenko for all your insights. This really cleared a lot of things for me. No one has written for SAM4 so I guess I won't be able to use itwith Arduino just yet. Appreciate your help.

Comment: If you're feeling adventurous, clever, and have a *lot* of time on your hands, you could write and maintain your own SAM4 core :)

Comment: Haha, I don't feel any of those things at the moment xD. I think I would rather switch to SAMD51 or SAME51 ICs; both of which do have arduino support from adafruit and sparkfun. Thanks !